# Deleted root certificats reappear automatically

Tags: windows, certificate, trusted-root-certificates

I'm trying to delete root certificates but they reappear automatically.

This is what I do:

1. I delete the hightlighted certificates (see picture below) in both the current user's certtificate store and the local computer's certificate store.[image]
2. I checked that no DigiCert certificate is in any of the other stores.
3. I right click on an .exe file that has been signed with a certificate that has both deleted certificates in the certification path and I chose the "Digital Signatures".
   Both deleted certificates appear in the certification path:[image]
4. Now the deleted certificates appear again in both the current user's and the local computer's certificate stores once the views have been refreshed.

Where do these reappearing root certificates come from?

Comment: Windows has a built in function to query unknown root certificates at Mictosoft and if available and trusted download it. I assume that after you delete the certificate the next check starts the query at MS and reinstalls the certificate.

Comment: @Robert is there a way to prevent Windows from querying unknown root certificates?

Comment: In win  pro version you can configure that using a group policy. Search for "Automatic Root Certificates Update"

Comment: "Is there a way to prevent Windows from querying unknown root certificates?" - The certificates you highlighted are not "unknown" certificates.  They are trusted root certificates signed by a valid root certificate authority.  However, the way to no longer trust the certificate, is to revoke the certificate.  **However, revoking that particular certificate, is not advised.**  They are being automatically reinstalled, since they are a valid root certificate authority certificate(s), trusted by Microsoft.  **You would want to revoke them at the machine level not the user level by the way.**

Comment: @Robert both your comments are very helpful. If you make this an answer, you have my upvote.

Comment: @Ramhound by "unknown certificates" I rather meant "certificates that are not in the computer's certificate store". Anyway the other comments answered my questions.